# LLVM Loop vectorizer does not vectorize my IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have generated LLVM IR code using an IRBuilder, and tried to run a LoopVectorizer on it, but it does not vectorize the code.

Here is my LLVM IR after the ModulePassManager has run on it:

```
; Function Attrs: argmemonly nofree norecurse nosync nounwind
define void @batch_function_0(ptr nocapture readonly %parameters, ptr nocapture readnone %series, ptr nocapture %state_vars, ptr nocapture readnone %solver_workspace, ptr nocapture readnone %date_time, double %fractional_step) local_unnamed_addr #1 {
entry:
  br label %loop

loop:                                             ; preds = %loop, %entry
  %index = phi i64 [ 0, %entry ], [ %next_iter, %loop ]
  %subtemp = add nuw nsw i64 %index, -100
  %var_ptr = getelementptr double, ptr %state_vars, i64 %subtemp
  %var = load double, ptr %var_ptr, align 8
  %addtemp = add nuw nsw i64 %index, 2
  %par_ptr = getelementptr double, ptr %parameters, i64 %addtemp
  %par = load double, ptr %par_ptr, align 8
  %fmultemp = fmul fast double %par, %var
  %var_ptr1 = getelementptr double, ptr %state_vars, i64 %index
  store double %fmultemp, ptr %var_ptr1, align 8
  %next_iter = add nuw nsw i64 %index, 1
  %loopcond.not = icmp eq i64 %next_iter, 100
  br i1 %loopcond.not, label %afterloop, label %loop

afterloop:                                        ; preds = %loop
  ret void
}
```

Here is how I set up the optimization passes:

```
llvm::LoopAnalysisManager     lam;
llvm::FunctionAnalysisManager fam;
llvm::CGSCCAnalysisManager    cgam;
llvm::ModuleAnalysisManager   mam;

llvm::PassBuilder pb;

pb.registerModuleAnalyses(mam);
pb.registerCGSCCAnalyses(cgam);
pb.registerFunctionAnalyses(fam);
pb.registerLoopAnalyses(lam);
pb.crossRegisterProxies(lam, fam, cgam, mam);

llvm::ModulePassManager mpm = pb.buildPerModuleDefaultPipeline(llvm::OptimizationLevel::O2);

mpm.addPass(llvm::createModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor(llvm::LoopVectorizePass()));

mpm.run(*data->module, mam);
```

What else do I need to do in order to get it to vectorize the loop?

For reference, the equivalent C++ function of what I try to represent in the IR would look something like this:

```
void
testfun(double *state_var, double *par) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        state_var[i] = state_var[i-100]*par[i+2];
    }
}
```

This loop is vectorized by clang if I compile it with -O2.
(Note that this is only included as a comparison, I am not generating my original IR from C++)

Comment: The C++ code is tricky to vectorize, because `par` and `state_var` must be assumed to potentially alias.  clang tests for this by comparing the pointers, and if they are too close to each other, falls back to a scalar version.  It may be that this transformation happens at a higher level in clang, before generating the IR.

Comment: I believe LLVM has some way to inform the optimizer "these pointers don't alias", somewhat like C's `restrict`, but I'm not that familiar with LLVM so I couldn't tell you what it is.

Comment: @NateEldredge You are right, clang has generated two branches, where it first checks the distance between the pointers to determine if it is safe to vectorize. If you put the __restrict keyword on the pointer arguments in the C++ code, clang omits the scalar version and safely assumes it can vectorize the loop. The IR generated has the 'noalias' attribute on the function arguments, which is the llvm version of restrict. However, I have now tried to put 'noalias' on the arguments in my IR, and it still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the 'noalias' attribute on the function parameters

```
fun->addParamAttr(idx, llvm::Attribute::NoAlias);
```

like discussed in the comments above, I found that I can force vectorization by setting

```
llvm::VectorizerParams::VectorizationFactor = 2;
```

In this case it turns out that it does not improve the speed of the code, so the lack of vectorization when not forced may just be the LLVM vectorization cost model being correct.
I am still a bit puzzled as to why clang would think it is a good idea to vectorize in this case.